# '>>>' Java to C++

Tags: c++, shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is >>> operation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529443/what-is-operation-in-c)

I need to convert this tiny little part of Java to C + +, but do not know what is '>>>' ... searched, but found no references, only on shift.
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
int x1;

x1 = text1[i1++] & 0xff;

text2[i2++] = (char) (x1 >>> 8);
```

Comment: It's the *unsigned* right shift operator. I'm really not sure what the C++ equivalent is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unsigned right shift (`>>>`) doesn't exist in C++, because it's not necessary -- C++ has distinct signed and unsigned integer types. If you want right shifts to be unsigned, make the variable that's being shifted unsigned:

```
unsigned int x1 = text1[i1++] & 0xff;
text2[i2++] = (char) (x1 >> 8);
```

That being said, the code you're translating is silly. The result of the second operation will always be zero in Java, so you could just as easily translate it to:

```
i1++;
text2[i2++] = 0;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't true: the cast doesn't magically affect the "context" of the expression that it's applied to.

Comment: It really was a duplicate post, My apologize.
The right way is:
text2 [i2 + +] = (char) (unsigned int) (x1 >> 8);
or
text2 [i2 + +] = (char) ((unsigned int) x1 >> 8);

Comment: Oops -- I missed the conversion to unsigned before the shift. My apologies.

Comment: It is actually a suite of tests to run multithreaded, need to convert this code to perform some tests on a parallel virtual machine.
I'm using from http://www2.epcc.ed.ac.uk/computing/research_activities/java_grande/index_1.html.

Comment: @Daniel: what's the point of accepting an answer then trying to tell us what the correct way is in a comment?  duskwuff is correct, and your comment wrong - (char)(unsigned int)(x1 >> 8) is a waste of time... the casts are uselessly applied after the shift has taken place on whatever the type of `x1` is.

Comment: But a `char` in Java is a 16-bit unsigned integer, so maybe you should cast to an `unsigned short`. But +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in C would be:

```
unsigned int x1;

x1 = text1[i1++] & 0xff;

text2[i2++] = (unsigned char)(x1 >> 8)
```

In C the shift operator will drag the 1 from the sign bit over if the variable it is operating on is signed, if not it will act like the java unsigned shift.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>>` operator in Java is a [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) equivalent to the `>>` operator in C++ on `unsigned` types. It shifts zeros into vacant bit positions on the left. On signed types, it’s implementation-defined whether a right shift is logical or [arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), so you need to use an unsigned type from the start (or cast):

```
unsigned int x1;
x1 = text1[i1++] & 0xff;
text2[i2++] = static_cast<char>(x1 >> 8);
```

Of course, this code doesn’t seem to make much sense—`x1` only has 8 non-zero bits because it was masked with `0xff`, so right-shifting it by 8 bits results in zero.